# Configure two way sync fileserver with sharepoint online library

Tags: sync, administrator, file-server, sharepoint-2013, sysadmin

As the title says, i have an on premise file server & i want to move to cloud and be able to:

1. users will have access to files from sharepoint online or on prem file server
2. sync data between two, if user changes file on prem it will update cloud, if user changed cloud version it will update on prem version
3. move all data with current permissions

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if two-way sync is even possible, but try this one-way sync script that checks the timestamp of each file in the given file share and uploads it to SharePoint Online if the file share has been updated.

In the same way, any file deleted in Fileshare will be deleted in SharePoint Online as well. It also generates a log file every time it runs. Please note this script does only one-way sync from Fileshare to SharePoint Online

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/07/sync-file-share-to-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html

Hope this helps.